# Figure out what is locking my AD account

Tags: windows, active-directory

Some process on my machine is locking out my active directory account due to it using the old password. I've searched all the normal things (services, IIS app pool, RDP sessions, credential vault) and I can't find anything that is set to use me as a user.

Does anyone know how I find what is using my old password?

Comment: Assume youve checked all email clients?

Comment: Yes I checked outlook as well really struggling. I logged into the AD controller and reset the password to my old password to see if it stops locking the account but I'm still going to have trouble finding out what program is using my password o_0. I can't believe windows does show this ?

Comment: Do you have access to the Domain Controllers? Sysinternals has a program to check the status of an account across all Domain controllers think its called lockoutstatus.exe. Download that and run it against your Domain Controllers, it will tell you the last bad password hit on a particular DC and how many bad password hits it has had. Take that Date/Time stamp and use it to check the event logs on the Domain Controller Security if your lucky the event stamp which used your credentials will have an originating IP and application that used it....

Comment: Done this already lol says it's coming from my P.C. every 2 (ish hours) but I can't find the service that is causing the issue. I even reset my password back to the original and it's still locking the account.

Comment: @Dave3of5 Hmm interesting. Did you happen to notice what Logon Type was should be a number. What about if you check your local event logs (application, security and system) at the same time do you notice anything happening on your machine at that time. Have you checked for any scheduled tasks that you might have created that have your credentials saved? What about Credential Manager in Windows any saved versions of your logon need updating?